# What is the difference between those two declarations?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to the C language and i can't figure out what is the difference between `char* stc[4];` and `char stc[4];`..

I know `char stc[4];` will create an array with 4 items but what creates the first one is a mystery to me..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this too broad? I thought it was a very specific question - minus the fluff, it's "What does `char* str[4];` declare?"

Answer (score 6):

`char *stc[4];` creates an array of 4 pointers to `char`. (Any introduction to C should explain pointers and declarations.)

Answer (score 2):

`char* stc[4]` is an array of pointers which stores **addresses** of 4 char datatype variables.

```
int main ()
{
   char  stc[] = {'a', 'b', 'c','d'};
   char *ptr[4];
   int i;

   for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      ptr[i] = &stc[i]; /* assign the address of char array elements. */
   }

}
```

Comment: objects, not variables.

Answer (score 2):

You should learn first what a pointer is in C. The first declaration allocates memory for holding 4 pointers to `char` values. The second declaration allocates memory for holding 4 `char` values.

A quick answer for what a pointer is, think about a library. A library contains items of type "book", and the librarian will give you a pointer (a post-it or a piece of paper) with information about the location of a book you are interested in. So, in analogy, the first declaration reserves memory for 4 post-its, and the second one reserves memory for 4 books.